Use .sh file to build image in docker compose
I have a docker compose file that works fine on my Windows/WSL environment. I am trying to deploy it to a Ubuntu server. I get the following error unable to prepare context: path "/home/dev/gestion_energetique/portainer/node_red/docker-alpine.sh.
The image is being built using a the docker-alpine.sh script. The file is there and has all the permissions (777). I have seen similar issues, but none helped me solve this problem. I'm assuming the issue is the .sh script but I have no idea how to work around that.
Any help is appreciated.
Here are the files I use
compose file:
services:
  nodered:
    container_name: nodered
    image: testing:node-red-build
    build: /home/dev/gestion_energetique/portainer/node_red/docker-alpine.sh
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 1880:1880
    # volumes:
    #   - ~/node_red/:/data/
  influxdb:
    container_name: influxdb
    image: influxdb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup 
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=${INFLUXDB_USERNAME}
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=${INFLUXDB_PASSWORD}
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=${INFLUXDB_ORG}
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=${INFLUXDB_BUCKET}
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN=${INFLUXDB_TOKEN}
    volumes:
      - /home/dev/gestion_energetique/portainer/data:/var/lib/influxdb2
      - /home/dev/gestion_energetique/portainer/config/influxdb:/etc/influxdb2
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    depends_on:
      - nodered
  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - /home/dev/gestion_energetique/portainer/data/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
      - /home/dev/gestion_energetique/portainer/config/grafana:/etc/grafana
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
  ihm:
    container_name: ihm
    build: /home/dev/gestion_energetique/portainer/.
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 1312:1312
    depends_on:
      - influxdb


docker-alpine.sh
#!/bin/bash
export NODE_RED_VERSION=$(grep -oE "\"node-red\": \"(\w*.\w*.\w*.\w*.\w*.)" package.json | cut -d\" -f4)

echo "#########################################################################"
echo "node-red version: ${NODE_RED_VERSION}"
echo "#########################################################################"

docker build --rm --no-cache \
    --build-arg ARCH=amd64 \
    --build-arg NODE_VERSION=20 \
    --build-arg NODE_RED_VERSION=${NODE_RED_VERSION} \
    --build-arg OS=alpine \
    --build-arg BUILD_DATE="$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")" \
    --build-arg TAG_SUFFIX=default \
    --file Dockerfile.custom \
    --tag testing:node-red-build .

Thank you !

I don't think Compose build: can run an arbitrary shell script; but the various options you show there can mostly go into the Compose build: block, or the couple that are dynamically computed can probably go directly into the Dockerfile in some form.

(My first instinct on looking at the question was to suggest the absolute /home/dev/... paths were causing problems trying to transplant this setup to a different machine.  Where Compose does use local files, for the build: { context: } and the left-hand side of volumes:, it will resolve relative paths relative to the location of the Compose files.  You also do not need to set container_name:, nor do you need to set both image: and build: together unless you're planning to push the built image to a registry.)

Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, chmod 777 is wrong and dangerous. You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably chmod 755) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Thanks @tripleee I will revert that. It is 100% private though.

@DavidMaze It is working fine on my local machine (using WSL) so it looks like Compose can run an aribitrary shell script. And The paths on the Docker Compose file are the absolute paths of the machine where I am trying to deploy the application. So you're saying I should try to use relative paths ?

According to the Compose Specification, if build: is a string, then it is either a directory containing the build context or a git://... URL pointing to a directory.  The same documentation notes that Compose "execute[s] a Docker build, looking for a canonical Dockerfile at the root of the directory".
Compose does not run an arbitrary shell script, and you should in fact get an error along the lines of "build context is not a directory".
It looks like what's in that script is mostly trying to provide build-time arguments.  The ones that are static or just pass through a host environment variable you can include in the Compose file
services:
  nodered:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.custom  # consider just "Dockerfile"
      args:
        ARCH: amd64                  # consider automatic `$TARGETARCH`
        NODE_VERSION: "20"
        NODE_RED_VERSION:            # intentionally empty to pass through from host
        OS: alpine
    image: testing:node-red-build    # optional if you're not pushing this image anywhere

The only variable that leaves is the build date.  You don't say how it's used in the Dockerfile, but you should be able to run the same date command in the RUN directive that actually uses the value, inside the Dockerfile.
